# JQuery hide in complete argument

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#newrecord1 tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#newrecord1 tr:odd(.odd)").find("li").hide();
    $("#newrecord1 tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#newrecord1 tr:first-child").show();    
    $("#newrecord1 tr.odd").click(function (){
        if ($(this).next("tr").css('display') === 'none'){
            $(this).next("tr").show();
            $(this).next("tr").find("li").slideDown("slow");
        }
        else {
            $(this).next("tr").find("li").slideUp("slow",function(){
                $(this).next("tr").hide();
            });
        }
    })
})
```

on the line number 13 the code line `$(this).next("tr").hide()` is not working when li tag slides up it is not hiding that row.

Comment: Can you prepare a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)** please?

Comment: will try its a big code though

Comment: Are you trying to hide the `<tr>` the `<li>` is in? because if so, after slideUp, you're trying to hide a `<tr>` that is next to that `<li>`.

Comment: I think you should use a reference like `var myTr = $(this).next("tr");` and use it.

Comment: yep, second $(this).next('tr') is pointing from the <li> instead of #newrecord1 tr.odd

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qvgUS/31/ @yckart

Comment: @kalley yea i am trying to hide the <tr> the <li> is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to rewrite this to fix your problem and be a little less intense (You are creating far too many new objects, and take advantage of chaining where you can):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var trs = $('#newrecord1').find('tr');
    var oddTRs = trs.filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
    // hide all <li>
    trs.find('li').hide();
    trs.filter(':not(.odd)').hide();
    trs.filter(':first-child').show();    
    oddTRs.click(function (){
        var nextTR = $(this).next('tr');
        if (nextTR.css('display') === 'none'){
            nextTR.show().find("li").slideDown("slow");
        }
        else {
            nextTR.find("li").slideUp("slow",function(){
                nextTR.hide();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Give this a try.

Comment: LOL! I was just going to paste exactly the same code!, not exactly, I had nextTr instead, but that was the only difference :)

Comment: kalley it works like a charm, but when i click for the first time, it does not slide down the next tr, it directly shows it

Comment: I updated it to hide the `<li>`s initially in all rows so that you will see what you're expecting.